# rails3 minitest bundle update give me register_spec_type undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, minitest

I'm just trying to get into testing an tried minitest. I finally got something working patterning after a Railscast, but tests were running twice. Saw something that said to do a bundle update. That led to several problems that I have cleared up except for:

```
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/minitest-rails-0.5.2/lib/minitest/rails.rb:34:in `<class:TestCase>': undefined method `register_spec_type' for ActionController::TestCase:Class (NoMethodError)
from /Users/salex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/minitest-rails-0.5.2/lib/minitest/rails.rb:32:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/salex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from /Users/salex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
from /Users/salex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/salex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from /Users/salex/work/aidtdbr/test/minitest_helper.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
...
```

which points to the `require "minitest/rails"` line in my minitest helper

my bundle

```
Using minitest (4.6.1) 
Using minitest-matchers (1.2.0) 
Using minitest-capybara (0.1.0) 
Using rails (3.2.11) 
Using minitest-rails (0.5.2) 
Using minitest-rails-capybara (0.5.1)
```

I reinstalled the minitest helper and just uncommented a few things

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "development"
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)

require "minitest/autorun"
require "minitest/rails" 
require "minitest/rails/capybara"

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.(yml|csv) for all tests in alphabetical order.
  fixtures :all

  # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...
end
```

This did not start off as a new application so I don't know if whatever was before minitest is what is messing up, but it did work for a little while.  I think my running twice was using `rake test` instead of `rake minitest`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default test_unit and mini_test railties are in contention within your app. To make sure your app is always configured to use minitest-rails, add the following to the `config/application.rb` file:

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.test_framework :mini_test
end
```

Alternatively, you can replace this line at the top of the `config/application.rb` file:

```
require "rails/all"
```

With this:

```
# Pick the frameworks you want:
require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "active_resource/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
# require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
require "minitest/rails/railtie"
```